# When was the viewer told about the vulnerability of the new Star Destroyers?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

In many reviews of *The Rise of Skywalker*, I have heard it said that the new Star Destroyers have a vulnerability that will make them very easy to destroy once their shields are down and that this fact is explicitly **stated** to be part of the The Resistance's plan.

Having seen the film, I know that the vulnerability is shown to exist, but when is this **said** as opposed to shown? Did I miss a line?

Comment: I think the assumption was just that unshielded ships were vulnerable, rather than a specific weakness of the new Star Destroyers. All I remember being explicitly stated was that they couldn't use their shields while in Exegol's atmosphere and that they couldn't leave atmosphere without the navigation signal. So the Resistance planned to disrupt the signal to keep them vulnerable to the hopefully-arriving larger attack force.

Comment: @Withad That matches my memory, but it makes the battle seem even more absurd. In particular, the scene where the Y-wing single-handedly destroys a Star Destroyer stands out.

Comment: It's a bit silly but I guess it's at least consistent with other Star Destroyer silliness. Once the Executor's shields were down in _Return of the Jedi_, a single fighter crashing into the bridge was enough to take out the whole ship.

Comment: Also most of the ships apparently lacked crews; there was a discussion aboard General Pryde's ship that that the First Order would need to resume "harvesting" children across the galaxy to staff the fleet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue isn't that they're *easy* to destroy, it's that once they're in outer space and moving, their shields will unfold and they'll be all but *impossible* to destroy. Hence why the Resistance need to go and gather some more ships and allies to help them with their attack.

The plan was outlined during the 'briefing' scene at 1:36:20. I've bolded the line about their explicit vulnerability to a shot to the guns.

> **Poe:** *Once those Star Destoyers are on Exegol, we can hit 'em.*
>
> **Rebel:** *Hit them how?*
>
> **Rebel woman:** *They can't activate their shields until they leave atmosphere*
>
> **Poe:** *Which isn't easy on Exegol. Ships that size, they need help taking off.*
>
> ...
>
> **Poe:** *Once the tower is down, the fleet'll be stuck in atmo for just minutes with no shields and no way out.*
>
> **Rose:** ***We think hitting the cannons might ignite the main reactors.***
>
> **Lando:** *That's our chance!*

Comment: Did you transcribe that yourself? I can't find a copy of the script online and I don't think it's out on DVD yet. Do you happen to have a copy of that clip handy?

Comment: @J.Mini - I just have an excellent memory and certainly didn't download a dodgy cam copy from piratebay. Because [that would be wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNXXpTsd_Co).

Comment: @Valorum Why do I suddenly having a coughing fit?

Comment: @Skooba - Try a lozenge.

Comment: You missed the main part (that the cannons are fed from main reactor) from novelizaton

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - I thought Rose saying it would be sufficient

Comment: @Valorum - no, that's just the conclusion, not why Rose came to that conclusion

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - I felt it was obvious that the mega-guns are powered by the main reactor. What else could be powering them?

Comment: @Valorum - you're not Disney canon